# Define initialized arrays in functions and return values based on user input Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In this application I need to allow users to enter a month as integer (1-12) then use integer tryparse to validate that input, that seems to be the easy part. I need two create two functions, one that returns the name of the month and the other returns the number of days in that month. The arrays are supposed to be defined and initialized within the function so that the main program can take the user input and call the two functions, then return the appropriate values as output to labels. I am not sure how to declare the arrays in their appropriate functions and then how to call those functions to retrieve the right value from the function.

Comment: Its a project for a class and I have been working on it for 3 days now and I just feel like I am over thinking it at this point. I'm not expecting anyone to do it for me i was just hoping for some pointers to get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework I'm not gonna write the code for you, but this should be pretty simple. Assuming the number is in the textbox and the user presses the OK button (or whatever the functionality is), the code for that OK button should include calls to the two functions you create, let's say GetMonth and GetDays.

GetMonth would take an integer, and frankly, I don't really see the need for declaring any arrays here. If the array declaration is part of your assignment then you *can* do that, but it just doesn't seem necessary. A simple `Select...Case` statement seems more straightforward: you just set up the cases for the integer being passed into the function, 1-12, and return the month's string. Similarly for GetDays, just set up cases 1-12 and return the number of days.

If you're unfamiliar with any of this, take a look at these MSDN articles; they should point you in the right direction:

[Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx)

[Cases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

[Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Edit: Realized I never expanded on how you could do this with arrays anyway (meant to, sorry). You would just create two string arrays of size 12 (or one string array, one integer array), and then define each of the 12 elements in each array as whatever month or number of days you need. Then in the function, just return something like `arrayDays[x]`, where x is the input being passed in. (If you want to be fancy, you could create a 12x2 string array and store all the information in one place.) But I'm pretty sure it'll take slightly less code to do a `Select...Case` statement (it just seems more direct to me).